# How do to I read in data from a text file which is carriage return line feed delimited to matlab?

Tags: matlab, text-files, carriage-return

I have a file which has a 32 line header of text, the rest is data (doubles) - one value on each line. Each line is carriage return line feed delimited. I have tried using:

```
 fscanf 
 sscanf 
 textscan
```

and:

```
 dlmread
```

This seemed the most likely option but I can't seem to work out how to specify a carriage return line feed as the delimiter. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Perhaps [fgetl](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html?refresh=true)?

Comment: Ill have a look, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`importdata`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) is the most suitable function.

Assuming you have a file like that:

[image]

```
import = importdata('data.txt','',3)
data = import.data
```

returns:

```
data =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
```

If you have multiple columns you can specify a delimiter:

```
importdata('data.txt','\t',3)
```

but for just one column it doesn't matter.